# Matching strings between symbols

Tags: regex

It's a few days I'm trying to solve this issue but I can't make it work.
I have looked at many questions here on Stack-overflow but still I can't figure out the correct way to solve it.

I have string representing arithmetic expressions with numbers and "multi word" variables such as `(Car speed / Road-congestion Time) + 100` and I need to match everything but `+-*/()`.

I need to get the following three matches:

- Car speed
- Road-congestion Time
- 100

The following expression kind of work (it adds an extra empty match at the end) `[+-\\*\\/()]?([^+-\\*\\/()]*)[+-\\*\\/()]?` for string without hyphens in the "multi word" variables. To distinguish minus signs and hyphens, the minus signs are always surrounded by spaces but I can't figure out how to specify that in the regexp.

Any ideas how to update my regexp to fit all the cases?
As a plus, the regexp should ignore numbers (get only the first two matches in the example above).

PS - Splitting is the last option and if possible I'd like to use a regular expression.

Comment: Contradiction: *"I need to match everything but `+-*/()`"* versus *"matches: ... Road-congestion"*. Should the hyphen match or not?

Comment: When it's not surrounded by spaces yes (as in Road-congestion). When it's surrounded by spaces  no (as in 2 - 1). Thanks

Comment: `[^\s\-+*\/()][^\-+*\/()]*(?:(?<!\s)-(?!\s)[^\-+*\/()]+)*(?<!\s)`? See https://regex101.com/r/8lR696/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your help. That regexp seems to work. Is there a way not to match numbers (the 100 in my example).

Comment: What if the string were `"(Car speed / Road-congestion Time + 100"` or `"(Car speed */ Road-congestion Time) + 100"` or some other string that contains a formatting error from a mathematical point of view? Are there no matches in that case? If you don't check that in the regex--assuming it's never a problem--it seems you could just match `\b(?:[a-zA-Z]+|\d+)(?:(?:\s+|-)(?:[a-zA-Z]|\d)+)*\b`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pbxP2s/1)

Comment: What's wrong with splitting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
\b(?:[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*|\d+)\b
```

This is the result on *https://regex101.com/* :

[image]

**In this pattern:**

- `\b` asserts a word boundary to ensure that we are matching whole
  words.
- `(?: ... )` is a non-capturing group to match either multi-word
  variables or numbers.
- `[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*` matches multi-word variables.
  It starts with a letter and can contain letters, numbers, hyphens,
  underscores, and spaces.
- `|` is the alternation operator, allowing the pattern to match either
  multi-word variables or numbers.
- `\d+` matches one or more digits for numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even better is `/\b(?:[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*)\b/` which skips the numbers.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Your link may broken in future and in does not permit users from seeing the results of modifications of your code or test strings. Instead, just give the link to regex101, like this: [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JsN0N6/1). We can be confident that it is unlikely that links to regex101.com will be broken in, say, the next millennium. That link, incidentally, illustrates a weakness of your regex.